# Why dbms_stats.gather_table_stats required?

Tags: oracle, optimizer-statistics

What is parameters description for gather_table_stats? Can we validate record, which we inserted by same.

Comment: What have you tryed so far?

Comment: DBMS_STATS deals with optimizer statistics. It, as well as its procedures, is described in documentation. What do you mean by "validating inserted record"? Could you explain that question?

Comment: You can find the documentation for all parameters in [the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#ARPLS68582). Details on how Oracle uses those statistics can also be found [in the manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_statscon.htm#TGSQL336)